# Python: Get information after link binding partial Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import functools
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
def func(win,name):
    print (name)
mylist = ['item1','item2','item3']
for item in mylist:
    link1=Label(win,text=item)
    link1.bind("<Button-1>",functools.partial(func,item))
    link1.pack()
    
win.mainloop()
```

My code currently outputs "ButtonPress event num=1 x=10 y=10>" whereas it should output item 1,2 or 3 when the label is pressed.
When buttons are used instead it works perfectly fine but once it's a binded Label it gives a different output

Comment: please provide a more complete [mre], it is not quite understandable what the actual issue is

Comment: @Matiiss thank you and apologies.

Comment: use `print(win)`

Answer (score 0):

A Button command calls a function with no parameters `func()`. Any function bound to a `"<Button-1>"` event is passed the event, `func(event)`.

In the original code:

```
def func(win,name):
    print (name)

functools.partial(func,item)
# This sets the **win** parameter to item.  When the new function is called 
# the **event** is passed to the next 'available' parameter, name.
```

This works when the partial is called from a button command as no parameters are passed.  When called from a bound event an event parameter is passed. This is what is printed when the Label is clicked.

```
import functools
from tkinter import *
    
win = Tk()
def func( event, name ):
    print ("Event: ", event, "Name: ", name)

mylist = ['item1','item2','item3']
for item in mylist:
    link1=Label(win,text=item)
    link1.bind("<Button-1>",functools.partial(func,name = item))
                           # set the name parameter explicitly
    link1.pack()
    
win.mainloop()
```